# Widget using "display on anchor categroy" not working on magento 2

Tags: category-products, widget

This is driving me nuts, i'm trying to show a static block on the right sidebar of each product based on the category they are in. But it won't show anything on the frontend !

When i use the "display on all product types" it works instantly. I've read loads of suggestion on the internet but none worked for me. Here is a screenshot of what i'm doing :

[image]
[image]

- The static block is active (shows when i select "display on all product")
- The theme is Olegnax athlete
- The category and sub-categories are anchored
- The category and sub-categories have the "display mode" on "static blocks and products"
- Tried to purge cache and reindex.

Hope someone can help me on this... i'm tired of adding the product each time a new one is created !!

Regards,
Marc

Comment: Anyone ? I'm stuck ;(

Comment: Still no one ? I'm seeing a lot of people complaining about this and nobody clearly identified the problem.